# Pypcap for mac on python 2.6?

Tags: python, pcap, packet-sniffers

How do you end up running pypcap for python 2.6 on a mac?  It seems that there hasn't been any new releases since 2.5 or am I just looking in the wrong places?

I seem to be unable to install the 2.5 binary with the following error: You cannot install pcap 1.1 on this volume. pcap requires System Python 2.5 to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.5 code should run fine unaltered on Python 2.6 (you'll just occasionaly get a `DeprecationWarning` for features which are changing in Python 3.x).

Comment: It won't let me install it from the mac binary... I get the following error message: You cannot install pcap 1.1 on this volume. pcap requires System Python 2.5 to install.

Comment: Ah ok. Try installing the source by downloading the tarball, untarring it, running `python setup.py configure` , `python setup.py build` (and if that succeeds) `sudo python setup.py install` in succession. You'll  need Xcode (for gcc and the likes) installed.

Comment: hmm... running "python setup.py" on it gives error: no commands supplied.  I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Well you'd need to run `python setup.py configure` first, then `python setup.py build` (and if this succeeds) then `sudo python setup.py install`.

Comment: Yeah, tried that and got "invalid command configure".  Just realized it's config for this package though!  Huge thanks :)